# How to decrease the amount of API calls my website makes

Tags: php, api, limit, rate

The situation is as follows:

I have a PHP website that connects to an Amazon like API to retrieve data of several thousants products.

For each product i get an XML. I 'file_get_contents' that XML and echo the data on my website. On the fly, so no backing up / saving those XML to my webserver. If the data (like stock info) changes at the remote site (Amazon like), the stockinfo is immediately visible on my website.

I hope you understand my situation. No the problem:

Since a few days, the Amazon like website returns a 'Too Many Requests 429' error and no data is on my website any more.

For 2 years there was no problem. But now i think the Amazon like website tighten there rate limits OR i get more and more visitors (real visitors or searchbot).

The rate limit at Amazon like is set to 1200 request per hour. My website got more than 2000 hits in 1 hour so i understand the couse of the error.

Now... what is the best way to avoid future errors?

Do i need to store those thousand XML files to my webserver or in a database so i do not have to connect to the API so many times.

Or is there any other solution? Maybe a time out? Or should i 'ask' google to not index my website so many times? Or can it be done with caching in httaccess maybe? If yes... could you please give me a piece of code i can use to help me out?

I use the following code. And all 2000 hits in 1 hour use this code:

```
$url = "https://amazonlikewebsite.com/catalog/v4/lists/?ids=123&limit=30&dataoutput=refinements&apikey=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&format=xml";
                    
$content = file_get_contents($url);
$xml = simplexml_load_string($content);
                    
foreach ($xml->products as $product) {

    // echo data of the products
}
```

Comment: Best way would be to cache the results, and only refetch if they're past a certain age and you haven't yet gone over your rate limit. That means you need to determine Amazon's rate limit, as well as a maximum acceptable age for data. You can probably get away with caching the result on your filesystem since all you need to track is the age, which the filesystem will tell you.

Comment: @kmoser has you covered in their comment, Id add that using Memcache to store the results might be a more efficient solution as it would cut out a significant amount of file IO reading and writing all the local xml files or doing database calls as well as being slightly simpler to invalidate old results.